# Why does my number seem to be an object in React?

Tags: reactjs

My class is defined:

```
class MyPage extends React.Component<MyPage Props, {startTypeValue: number}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { startTypeValue: 0 };...
```

later I look at `startTypeValue`:

```
const val=JSON.stringify(this.state.startTypeValue, undefined, 2);
console.log( {val});
```

this displays what I would expect, `{val: "0"}`.

Now I set the value of `startTypeValue` by doing a DB call:

```
await this.startTypeGetPromise(this.props.someval).then((ret) =>
 this.setState({startTypeValue: ret}));
```

now I display `startTypeValue` again:

```
const aval=this.state.startTypeValue;
console.log( {aval});
```

which gives: `aval: startType: 1`. Now `startType` is the name of the db variable so this is what I expect to be returned, but `startTypeValue` is defined as `number` so how come it shows as this? More importantly how do I set `startTypeValue` to 1 rather than to  `startType: 1`?

Comment: Why name a variable `xxxValue` in the first place? The `Value` part doesn't add anything useful to the name. Every variable holds a value anyways. `startType` is a more reasonable variable name.

Comment: Yeah fair point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
await this.startTypeGetPromise(this.props.someval).then((ret) =>
 this.setState({startTypeValue: ret.startType}));
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me: `Property 'startType' does not exist on type 'number'`.

Comment: @schoon This seems to be a typescript error. Probably your `ret` is typed to be a `number` but it actually isn't a number. Note that typescript does no runtime checks. Likely the value that your promise resolves with is not correctly typed. Typescript does not enforce any types at runtime it just declares and checks the expected types as defined at compile time by the developer, not the actual ones.

Comment: @trixn you were right, thanks. I set it to any and with Yu Miao's answer it worked.

Comment: @schoon That fixes the warning but the correct way to resolve this would be to define a type that matches the response. Because now you have broken any further type checking on the response.